# Android No "Open" button at install and no icon in application list

Tags: android

I have uploaded an apk file in the google play. I have downloaded it and installed it. But open Button is disabled. app is not in the application list.

My manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="bengaltech.criketteam.mycricket.Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="SignUp"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="CreateTeam"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="CountryList"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="PlayerList"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="DashBoardActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="AddTeamName"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

I am giving you the manifest. I have added many activity here.

Comment: Which app is it? Did you specify your main and launcher activity? More info please.

Comment: yes definitely . This is not coding problem .

Comment: Which app is it? Does the developer console say anything?

Comment: Can you post your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your application enable by removing the tag `android:enabled="false"`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Usually we don't use this tag explicitly, just take the default value.

> android:enabled
>
> Whether or not the Android system can instantiate
> components of the application — "true" if it can, and "false" if not.
> If the value is "true", each component's enabled attribute determines
> whether that component is enabled or not. If the value is "false", it
> overrides the component-specific values; all components are disabled.
> The default value is "true".

Answer (score 0):

If you had the apk install on your device (from eclipse or android studio) before downloading it from Google play, it will not be on your application list. Try delete it from your device and download it from Google play again. It will solve your problem.